# jekyll not updating static CSS, HTML files in docker development container

Tags: ruby, docker, jekyll

I am debugging an issue where I am doing my development inside of a [Docker](http://docker.com/) container, but [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) is not properly updating static HTML or CSS files after the first time it has been written. I have added the following code to [`static_file.rb`](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/static_file.rb#L83) after line 83:

```
  sha256_src = Digest::SHA256.file path
  sha256_dst = Digest::SHA256.file dest_path

  fail "invalid file copy: #{path} / #{dest_path}" unless sha256_src == sha256_dst
```

And I see that the fail triggered because the hash does not match. Instead, an older version of the static file at `path` has been copied to `dest_path`. I thought I was losing my mind, but I know that Docker uses layered file systems and so I wonder if I am hitting some kind of bug or known issue.

Are there any known issues with using the following technologies in tandem with each other:

- [Jekyll](https://github.com/jekyll)
- Docker containers
- Linux containers
- [FileUtils cp method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp)
- Ruby 2.2.3p173

I have had to work around it by running the following command:

```
cp s5/*.css _site/s5/
cp s5/*.html _site/s5/
```

Instead of having it work automatically for me with [`jekyll build`](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/usage/).

---

Here is how I am linking my files to the docker image:

```
export ABSPATH=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; cd ../; pwd)
docker run -d --name static -t -i -p 4000:4000 -p 2422:22 --link static-db:db -v "$ABSPATH:/mnt/app" me/static:0.0.2 /sbin/my_init --enable-insecure-key
```

Docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.8.3
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   f4bf5c7
 Built:        Mon Oct 12 18:01:15 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.8.3
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   f4bf5c7
 Built:        Mon Oct 12 18:01:15 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Docker info:

```
Containers: 10
Images: 265
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 285
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 4.1.10-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 1.8.3 (TCL 6.4); master : af8b089 - Mon Oct 12 18:56:54 UTC 2015
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 3.859 GiB
Name: dev
ID: ZY6F:2VSO:EDRL:TWYE:JAS6:5GC3:PPAO:TNA6:KCCB:HFLC:4IQB:5BYE
Debug mode (server): true
File Descriptors: 21
Goroutines: 33
System Time: 2015-10-18T18:36:20.08630971Z
EventsListeners: 0
Init SHA1: 
Init Path: /usr/local/bin/docker
Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
Username: me
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
 provider=virtualbox
```

I am running this linked to a volume on OSX.

---

Here is an interactive session using binding.pry inside of static_file.rb. You can see that FileUtils.cp is not working properly.

In step 9-10 one can see I am manually invoking the `FileUtils::cp` command, and the resulting file hash is `aa75cd...`. I even try using `FileUtils.cp` to copy my original file to a different file path without success. However, in step 20-21, when I invoke the shell cp command directly using `cp`, it works and the resulting file has the proper hash of `724707...`.

```
Parsing Haml layouts...done.
Parsing Scss layouts...done.
Configuration file: /mnt/app/_config.yml
            Source: /mnt/app
       Destination: /mnt/app/_site
      Generating... 

From: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/static_file.rb @ line 92 Jekyll::StaticFile#write:

    77: def write(dest)
    78:   dest_path = destination(dest)
    79: 
    80:   return false if File.exist?(dest_path) and !modified?
    81:   @@mtimes[path] = mtime
    82: 
    83:   FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(dest_path))
    84:   FileUtils.rm(dest_path) if File.exist?(dest_path)
    85: 
    86:   FileUtils.cp(path, dest_path)
    87: 
    88:   sha256_src = Digest::SHA256.file path
    89:   sha256_dst = Digest::SHA256.file dest_path
    90: 
    91:   if sha256_src != sha256_dst
 => 92:     binding.pry
    93:   end
    94:   puts "invalid file copy: #{path} / #{dest_path}" unless sha256_src == sha256_dst
    95: 
    96:   true
    97: end

[1] pry(#<Jekyll::StaticFile>)> path
=> "/mnt/app/styles/scruff5.css"
[2] pry(#<Jekyll::StaticFile>)> dest_path
=> "/mnt/app/_site/styles/scruff5.css"
[3] pry(#<Jekyll::StaticFile>)> Digest::SHA256.file path
=> #<Digest::SHA256: 72470716291c6fef0c8c2151a0d0997f0991396cda964ba48e3cbb65cc7f7908>
[4] pry(#<Jekyll::StaticFile>)> Digest::SHA256.file dest_path
=> #<Digest::SHA256: aa75cd20ddf51b86ec2344002532f08891e05eb1a0a9f7e5f99d8fda05c5c920>
[5] pry(#<Jekyll::StaticFile>)> dest_path
=> "/mnt/app/_site/styles/scruff5.css"
[6] pry(#<Jekyll::StaticFile>)> FileUtils.rm(dest_path)
=> ["/mnt/app/_site/styles/scruff5.css"]
[7] pry(#<Jekyll::StaticFile>)> Digest::SHA256.file dest_path
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /mnt/app/_site/styles/scruff5.css
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/digest.rb:49:in `initialize'
[8] pry(#<Jekyll::StaticFile>)> Digest::SHA256.file path
=> #<Digest::SHA256: 72470716291c6fef0c8c2151a0d0997f0991396cda964ba48e3cbb65cc7f7908>
[9] pry(#<Jekyll::StaticFile>)> FileUtils.cp(path, dest_path)
=> nil
[10] pry(#<Jekyll::StaticFile>)> Digest::SHA256.file dest_path
=> #<Digest::SHA256: aa75cd20ddf51b86ec2344002532f08891e05eb1a0a9f7e5f99d8fda05c5c920>
[11] pry(#<Jekyll::StaticFile>)> dest_path
=> "/mnt/app/_site/styles/scruff5.css"
[12] pry(#<Jekyll::StaticFile>)> dest_path = dest_path + '-2'
=> "/mnt/app/_site/styles/scruff5.css-2"
[13] pry(#<Jekyll::StaticFile>)> FileUtils.cp(path, dest_path)
=> nil
[14] pry(#<Jekyll::StaticFile>)> FileUtils.cp(path, dest_path)
=> nil
[15] pry(#<Jekyll::StaticFile>)> Digest::SHA256.file dest_path
=> #<Digest::SHA256: aa75cd20ddf51b86ec2344002532f08891e05eb1a0a9f7e5f99d8fda05c5c920>
[16] pry(#<Jekyll::StaticFile>)> (Digest::SHA256.file dest_path).hexdigest
=> "aa75cd20ddf51b86ec2344002532f08891e05eb1a0a9f7e5f99d8fda05c5c920"
[17] pry(#<Jekyll::StaticFile>)> (Digest::SHA256.file path).hexdigest
=> "72470716291c6fef0c8c2151a0d0997f0991396cda964ba48e3cbb65cc7f7908"
[18] pry(#<Jekyll::StaticFile>)> FileUtils.rm dest_path
=> ["/mnt/app/_site/styles/scruff5.css-2"]
[19] pry(#<Jekyll::StaticFile>)> dest_path = '/mnt/app/_site/styles/scruff5.css'
=> "/mnt/app/_site/styles/scruff5.css"
[20] pry(#<Jekyll::StaticFile>)> `cp #{path} #{dest_path}`
=> ""
[21] pry(#<Jekyll::StaticFile>)> Digest::SHA256.file dest_path
=> #<Digest::SHA256: 72470716291c6fef0c8c2151a0d0997f0991396cda964ba48e3cbb65cc7f7908>
[22] pry(#<Jekyll::StaticFile>)>
```

Comment: How are you adding your files to the container/image? How is it built? Can you add the output of `docker version` and `docker info`?

Comment: @thaJeztah updated my answer and included a most puzzling interactive binding.pry session...

Comment: Have you tried launching the jekyll server locally, outside of docker? Your bounty says the jekyll cannot copy static files "anymore". What changes have you made to your site, jekyll config, or environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing the above analysis and determining that `[FileUtils.cp][1]` seemed to be at the root of this issue, I downgraded from Ruby 2.2.1 to Ruby 2.1.7p400, and this issue now appears to be corrected. It would appear that Ruby 2.2.1 has a potentially version serious regression in `FileUtils`.